# How to choose date of birth in calendar

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

One form input as Date of Birth choose calendar front end and store as mysqli.

I don't have an idea anybody say how to do. Because i'm new in php.

Comment: Please show what you have done uptil.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

Try this one to take date of birth from user.

Then convert in PHP

```
<?php
    $dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['bday']));
?>
```

Comment: Excellent!!!. But Mysqli how to store i need yyyy-mm-dd format. This format stored correct or worng?

Comment: Well, you can convert this format into MySQLi Format like 

$newDOB = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateofbirth));

Comment: Sorry for this question ask?
how to convert
This code where put?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UIs Datepicker. You can find its documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Let's first include and initiate the plugin

```
 /* include files needed */
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

/* initiate plugin */
<script>
  $( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
</script>
```

The selector would be your date `input` which would look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date">
```

Then store the date the way you usually do. Remember the date format must be `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type="date" name="birthDate">

$birthDate = $_POST['birthDate'];
```

using strtotime you can store date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
$newDOB = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($birthDate));
```

Comment: @sarathi any updates ? up-vote and accept the answer if helped thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below four steps to complete your requirement setup. Just you need to create db structure.

**1.** Configure Datepicker to provide dates in a supported format using an altField(http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) together with its altFormat option:

```
<input type="hidden" id="actualDate" name="actualDate"/>
$( "selector" ).datepicker({
    altField : "#actualDate"
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
});
```

Or, if you're happy for users to see the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, simply set the [dateFormat option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) instead:

```
$( "selector" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
});
```

**2.** Use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() function to convert the string:

```
INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

**3.** Convert the string received from jQuery into something that PHP understands as a date, such as a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_POST['date']);
and then either:
```

*- obtain a suitable formatted string:*

```
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

*- obtain the UNIX timestamp:*

```
$timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();

which is then passed directly to MySQL's [FROM_UNIXTIME()][3] function:

INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))
```

**4.** Manually manipulate the string into a valid literal:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
$date  = "$parts[2]-$parts[0]-$parts[1]";
```

Hope this help you well!